# Using a list template in ansible

Tags: list, templates, variables, ansible

I'm looking forward to configure switches using ansible. To do so, I made a variable file looking like this :

```
interfaces:
  - int g1/1:
    - desc ESX1
    - switchport mode access
    - switchport access vlan 10
  - int g1/2:
    - desc ESX2
    - switchport mode access
    - switchport access vlan 10
  - int g1/3:
    - desc ESX3
    - switchport mode access
    - switchport access vlan 10
```

This code is then read by a task like this :

```
- name: Configuration interfaces
  ios_config:
    lines: "{{ item[item.keys()[0]] }}"
    parents: "{{ item.keys()[0] }}"
    provider: "{{ provider }}"
  with_items: "{{ interfaces }}"
```

Would it be possible to define a template, such as :

```
template_esx:
  - switchport mode access
  - switchport access vlan 10
```

And to make my variable file look like this :

```
interfaces:
  - int g1/1:
    - desc ESX1
    {{ template_esx }}
  - int g1/2:
    - desc ESX2
    {{ template_esx }}
  - int g1/3:
    - desc ESX3
    {{ template_esx }}
```

Doing so, il would be able to modify all ports configuration changing only the template.

Is it possible ? What would be the syntax to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works :

```
template_esx:
  - switchport mode access
  - switchport access vlan 10
interfaces:
  - int g1/1: >
    {{ [
    u'desc ESX 1'
    ] + template_esx
    }}
```

But this breaks compatibility with https://github.com/leapfrogonline/ansible-merge-vars, that I also need :'(